# Cardinality of the Set of $\mathbb{C}$ valued sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Working a functional analysis question that I believe requires this and I'm struggling to determine this set's cardinality".

Comment: Have you any experience with cardinal arithmetic?

Comment: @DanielFischer, I haven't had any experience beyond say the most basic countability arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have experience with cardinal arithmetic, the following show that its size is the cardinality of the continuum:

First, $\mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$.  Thus, $$|\mathbb{C}|=|\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{R}|\cdot |\mathbb{R}|=\max\{|\mathbb{R}|,|\mathbb{R}|\}=|\mathbb{R}|$$

Next, we know that $|\mathbb{R}|=2^{\aleph_0}$ and thus from the above $|\mathbb{C}|=2^{\aleph_0}$, so that since you are considering the set $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$, we find that $$|\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{C}|^{|\mathbb{N}|}=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_0}=2^{\max\{\aleph_0,\aleph_0\}}=2^{\aleph_0}$$

In both of the above, I made use of the fact that for any two infinite cardinals $\kappa, \lambda$, we have $\lambda \cdot \kappa=\max\{\lambda, \kappa\}$.

Comment: thanks a bunch. I've literally never dealt with this type of cardinal arithmetic before. I didn't even know this would be the type of approach to take. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: A tangential comment: The fact that, for infinite cardinals, the product equals the maximum depends in general on the axiom of choice. The particular case in question, though, is provable without the axiom of choice.